# node-cron run job every 3 hours

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I am trying to run a node-cron job every 3 hours and I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Right now I am using:

```
* * */8 * * *
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should zero-out the second and minute values, and use a step of /3.
The cron expression for this is

```
0 0 */3 * * *
```

Which evaluates to 'At 0 seconds, 0 minutes every 3rd hour'.

Your current expression `* * */8 * * *` would try to run every second of every minute past every 8th hour.

Comment: great! just to mention that the seconds are optional in the cron expression