# Every 6 Hour cron pattern does not work with Nodejs cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, cron-task

I have a cron pattern `0 0 0/6 ? * *` for every six hour. i have used Nodejs cron for executing cron job, below is my code:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
  new CronJob('0 0 0/6 ? * *', function() {
          console.log(new Date(), 'Every 6 hours');
          try {
              // task to be executed
          } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
          }
      }, function() {},
      true
  ).start();
```

I got this exception during startup of my program:

```
"stack": [
    "Error: Field (?) cannot be parsed",
    "    at Object._parseField (/home/ajit/git/test/BackEnd/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:344:11)",
    "    at Object._parse (/home/ajit/git/test/BackEnd/node_modules/cron/lib/cron.js:308:9)",
```

I have checked this pattern at this website: http://www.cronmaker.com/ , it says my cron is valid . I have searched over internet and i am unable to get a valid 6 digit cron pattern without `?`.

Comment: My English knowledge says that: `? symbol/mark cannot be parsed, and I seet it first time` (: so fix is: `0 0 */6 * * *`  btw cronmaker can understand crons with minutes not with seconds, so it may say that it's ok (:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node-cron run job every 3 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597538/node-cron-run-job-every-3-hours)

Comment: I have tried this pattern `0 0 */6 * * *`  it is not working .

Comment: @AjitSoman how do You measure it? maybe Your code has issues?

Comment: Right now i have set my system time to `11:59 PM` , cron job does not trigger

Comment: of, course, You've set system type, but have You restarted Your app?

Comment: This cron job is for  1 min `0 */1 * * * *`, it execute correctly

Comment: also why not use simple `crontab` ?

Comment: try to log `console.log(new Date())`  on every tick of cron, seems like cron job has different timezone

Comment: I got this  for every one minutes : `2017-08-17T18:33:48.783Z`

Comment: @num8er , i have used your cron pattern 0 0 */6 * * * in our production server and based on logs i found that the cron is executing only one time at 12:00 AM . i am expecting this scheduler to run at 12:00 AM, 6:00 AM, 12:00 PM and 6:00 PM

Comment: @AjitSoman off course it will not work. Linux crontab does not have seconds. So it has read first 5 elements (0 0 */6 * *) and last star was implemented as command line thing. So fix Your crontab: 0 */6 * * *

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`Cron package documentation`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#available-cron-patterns),  patterns are based upon [this specification](http://crontab.org/). You can't use a `?` in the pattern.

Just replace the `?` by a `*`, same as the `0` before the `/6`:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
  new CronJob('0 0 */6 * * *', function() {
          console.log(new Date(), 'Every 6 hours');
          try {
              // task to be executed
          } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
          }
      }, function() {},
      true
  );
```

**EDIT**

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#another-cron-example) once again, it seems that the `true` flag passed as 3rd argument starts the job immediately so you don't have to call the `start` method.

Comment: i have set my system time to 11:59 PM but cron job does not trigger

Comment: i have checked your pattern at http://www.cronmaker.com/  it says invalid

Comment: Don't use cronmaker.com but https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#how-to-check-if-a-cron-pattern-is-valid

Comment: i have used your cron pattern `0 0 */6 * * *` in our production server and based on logs i found that the cron is executing only one time at 12:00 AM . i am expecting this scheduler to run at 12:00 AM, 6:00 AM, 12:00 PM and 6:00 PM

Comment: @AjitSoman off course it will not work. Linux crontab does not have seconds. So it has read first 5 elements (0 0 */6 * *) and last star was implemented as command line thing. So fix Your crontab: 0 */6 * * *